# Перенаправление с http на https

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

Добрый день.
 Стоит **Apache+nginx** в `.htaccess` добавляю

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com\.ua [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.com.ua$1 [R=301,L]
```

Пишет что `На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация`.

 Как поправить мне нужно такое перенаправление.

 P.s. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

Источник https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

2й вариант:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, если убрать этот реврайт для замены http на https и зайти на ваши сайт по http и по https, то что вы видите в 1м и во 2м случаях?

Comment: http -перенаправляет на https но даёт ошибку. если сразу то тоже самое ошибка без куда либо перенаправлений

Comment: То есть вы убрали из .htaccess все что относится к замене http на https и вас все равно перенаправляет с http на https? O_o

Comment: если нету перенаправлений то http - http , https - https

Comment: Ну так ответьте на мой вопрос:  ... и зайти на ваши сайт по http и по https, то что вы видите в 1м и во 2м случаях?

Comment: Добавил 2й вариант.

Comment: спасибо, вроде работает.

Comment: Второй вариант рабочий, спасибо =)

Comment: @Visman кинь плиз вариантик с доменом без www

Answer (score 2):

#### Причина ошибки

Циклическая переадресация возникает из-за использования вами логического "или": `[OR]`.
Смотрите, что происходит для адреса `http://site.com.ua [NC,OR]`:

1. Срабатывает условие `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com\.ua  [NC,OR]`
2. Срабатывает условие `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$ [NC]`
3. Происходит редирект на `https://site.com.ua`
4. Срабатывает условие `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com\.ua [NC,OR]`
5. Не срабатывает второе условие, но оно и не обязательно из-за `[OR]`
6. Происходит редирект на `https://site.com.ua`
7. Зацикливание, начиная с 4 пункта.

#### Решение

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com\.ua [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```