# После установки SSL-сертификата сайт отображается ненадёжным

Tags: ssl

Всем доброго дня! Помогите разобраться с ssl-сертификатом. Прописала в файле .htaccess эти строки:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} ^http$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf8
```

Сработал редирект с http://site.ru на https://site.ru Но когда я прописываю просто site.ru, то сайт отображается незащищённым. В чём может быть проблема и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вы с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/755113/186083 разобрались? Или вы мой комментарий к вашему вопросу не читали?

Comment: Ага, вижу, что разобрались. Только у вас ни какого редиректа нет.

Comment: Смотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440157/186083 разные условия определения, что пришли не по https.

Comment: Теперь я прописала вот этот код: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]. Но проблема теперь в другом, когда я захожу на другие ссылки на своём сайте выдаёт ошибку 404

Comment: Ни каких отличий не вижу. Редиректа как не было, так и нет. Страницы открываются без ошибки 404. В php сделайте `phpinfo();` и посмотрите в какой переменной информация о https или номер порта передается. И уже на основании этой информации редирект нужно делать.

Comment: Возможно вы удалили `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf8`, так этого делать не надо было.